# UIActivityViewController limit of images?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Is there a limit for the UIActivityViewController for sharing images? I crash if I am sharing too many UIImages, which makes sense since all these photos are loaded into memory.

Maybe there is another way to share?

Comment: Just run into the same issue.. Too many images fail silently. It will just close the share popup. If I reduce the number, it goes through. Problem is, it's really not predictable and there's no way to ask for the limit or get some related error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i am not sure it is smart to do so, but you can setup a "whitelist" of trusted activity providers. 
Then use UIActivityItemProvider with UIActivityItemSource protocol. You'll get calls on:

```
 (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController
 itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
```

Check the activityType. If it is on ur whitelist of trusted providers, return the data item. If the activitytype isn't recognised, return nil

Untrusted activities may still show up in the Activity sheet, but they won't get data with which to cause a problem for your app.